# Searching by ObjectId on Mongo Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

How does one use Mongo Compass and search by ObjectID? I've been searching for the documentation for this but haven't been successful with anything. I have tried:

```
{ "_id" : "58f8085dc1840e050034d98f" }

{ "$oid" : "58f8085dc1840e050034d98f" }

{ "id" : "58f8085dc1840e050034d98f" }
```

None of those seem to work and it's getting quite frustrating. Also, sidenote - is it possible to set the skip/limit when displaying documents in Compass?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

**UPDATE** Newer versions of Compass now support querying ObjectId similar to how they would be queried via the mongo shell (the `$oid` syntax will *not* work in these newer versions):

```
{_id: ObjectId('58f8085dc1840e050034d98f')}
```

If you're using an older version before 1.10.x you, enter the following into the query box:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"58f8085dc1840e050034d98f"}}
```

It's also worth pointing out that in the UI you can click on one of the _ids and it will auto-populate the query box with the query based on what you clicked. You can also shift+click on multiple fields to create compound (and-ed) query criteria, or you can click and drag to select a range.

Skip and Limit are support for versions >= 1.8.x **does** support skip and limit when browsing under the Documents tab. Click the "Options" button on the right side of the Query Bar. See the [Query Bar](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/query-bar/) docs for illustration and details.

The Schema tab only supports limit, as this will do a sampling of documents and skip doesn't really make sense in that context.

In order to click on the _ids you need to be on the [Schema](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/schema/) tab. If your _ids are of type ObjectId, the visualization of the distribution will appear as a date range and you can drag over one or more lines to populate the query based on _id. If your _ids are some other type, some portion of them will display individually and you can click, drag, or shift-click over them.

Comment: See my note in my edited answer regarding clicking on the _id. That will make your life even easier. :-)

Comment: @helmy does this still work? I'm clicking on `_id` but nothing happens

Comment: @nachocab you have to click on the values you want to query for, on the `SCHEMA` section. Here's the relevant section in the manual: https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/schema/#build-query

Comment: I just wonder - why `$oid` got deprecated? In source code, having to import ObjectId as a class to build the id seems like an unnecessary step.

Comment: It seems not working: the FIND button is not clickable :( No one of the two solutions proposed...

Comment: {_id: new BSON.ObjectId(“58f8085dc1840e050034d98f”)}

Answer (score 32):

The current version of MongoDB Compass (1.10.5) no longer appears to support `$oid`, but it does work with a standard query: `{"_id":ObjectId("5a028baa2dc80f2e26a8ed63")}`

Comment: Most relevant answer!

Comment: With Compass v1.21.2 on Windows 10 this syntax {"_id":ObjectId("5ec95f4bca1dd731c006f44e")} works for me

Answer (score 4):

{"_id":ObjectId("5f8344e2a00ed7f6172a7184")}

Answer (score 3):

```
{module_id: ObjectId('5cee65f283774d3470fc01cc')}
```

**Search Result:**
[image: search result]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In my case replaced "module_id" with only "_id"

Answer (score 0):

On MongoDB compass Version 1.36.3 (1.36.3) the following query is working for me to search for a ObjectId in a collection

```
{ _id: ObjectId('99228b69ebefdf6599311190e') }
```